# How to debug a DnnApiController using Fiddler?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke

Here is the DnnApiController documentation which I followed to the letter

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/3541/WebAPI-Tips.aspx

Unfortunately, the documentation does not explain how to integrate the class library into Dnn.   The documentation appears to suggest that it is possible to browse a Dnn solution configured on your local IIS such as

```
http://dotnetnuke/DesktopModules/MyServices/API/RoleSubScription/GetPublicRoles
```

where RoleSubscription is the RoleSubscriptionController and GetPublicRoles is a GET method.

I have debugged a Web API controller method through Fiddler but I used the MVC 4 Wep API project and it worked flawlessly, I was able to debug it using IIS express and the Fiddler composer using the IIS express Url.

As I see it, there are a few options for debugging this DnnApiController I have created

1. Try to run the class library project itself - this would require converting the class library project into some sort of web app project.
2. Create an MVC 4 Web API project and add the appropriate assemblies and configuration as suggested in the Dnn web api tips = this looks like the best option and the one that I will probably try first.
3. Add the classes I created to a folder structure under DestktopModules in my local IIS installation of the latest version of Dnn - this wont work with IIS express.
4. If I want to use IIS express, I can add the classes to a folder structure under Desktop Modules in my file system version of Dnn - this might work.

Comment: What error does it give you when you browse to the GetPublicRoles method? You will need to add the class to the (bin) folder within your DotNetNuke installation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out this HelloWorld example and see if it helps you in any way.

[DotNetNuke WebAPI HelloWorld Example – Part One](http://talkdotnet.wordpress.com/2014/03/18/dotnetnuke-webapi-helloworld-example-part-one/)

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, thanks. The approach in the link above does work.  I used a class library and pointed the build target to the main bin folder of DNN.  I debugged it in two ways, first using the URL structure suggested in the example and then I added a module to DNN and accessed the Web API method using a jQuery .ajax call.  I used Newtonsoft.Json to convert the DnnContent object to json.

Here is the DnnApiController Class

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace DnnModule
{
    public class DnnContentController : DnnApiController
    {
        private IDnnContentRepository _dbRepository;
        public DnnContentController()
        {
            _dbRepository = new DnnContentRepository();

        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetContent(int id)
        {
            if (id != 0)
            {
                var dnnContent = new DnnContent
                {
                    Content = _dbRepository.GetContent(id),
                    Title = _dbRepository.GetTitle(id)
                };
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dnnContent));
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(string.Empty));
        }
    }
}


public class DnnContent
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the UI code for the Dnn Module User Control

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DnnContentViewer.ascx.cs" Inherits="DnnModule.DnnContentViewer" %>

<h2>IngenMobile DNN Content Viewer</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#getDnn").click(function () {
            var id = $("#id").val();
            GetDnnContent(id);
        });
    });
    function GetDnnContent(moduleId) {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'DesktopModules/DnnModule/api/DnnContent/GetContent?id=' + id,
            type: 'GET',

            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('#result').html("Title: " + obj.Title + "</br>" + "Content: " + htmlDecode(obj.Content));
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                $('#result').html('Error: ' + request.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
    function htmlDecode(value) {
        if (value) {
            return $('<div />').html(value).text();
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
</script>
Enter id: <input type="text" id="id" value="" />
<input id="getDnn" type="button" value="Submit" />
<hr/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

I did have an issue with getting a not found response.  The problem was that I used a module name with a '.' in it.  When I took the '.' out of the module name, it worked.

Comment: Rather than returning a JSON string, you should try returning the object itself.  Then you give the client the ability to specify how it should be serialized (i.e. serializing is no longer a concern of your controller, but it is taken care of by the framework).